# Hibernate Spring - One to many

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on a JEE school project which is done with Spring and Hibernate. My tables are :

### INFRACTION

id_infraction

description

### DOSSIER

id_dossier

description

gravite

### INFRACTIONDOSSIER

id_dossier

id_infraction

The application does work well for adding "infractions" and "dossiers" and retrieve them in jsp pages.

The app should be able to add multiple "infractions" to one "dossier", and that is where i'm blocked;
I'm learning One-to-many tags and implemented them in my "Dossier" Class, but as I want a form separated from the adding infraction and adding dossier ones, I don't know how to handle that.

Here is the code I added in my Dossier class :

```
@OneToMany
private Set<Infraction> infractions;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "DOSSIERINFRACTION",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_dossier"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_infraction")
)
```

And my AppController class part handling adding Dossiers

```
/*
 * Méthode d'ajout d'un dossier
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newDossier(ModelMap model) {
    Dossier dossier = new Dossier();
    model.addAttribute("dossier", dossier);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    return "registration";
}

/*
 * Gère l'envoi du POST pour l'ajout de dossier ainsi que la validation du
 * formulaire
 * 
 */
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveDossier(@Valid Dossier dossier, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    service.saveDossier(dossier);

    model.addAttribute("success", "Dossier " + dossier.getNom() + " enregistré");
    return "success";
}
```

JSP form to record a dossier

```
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="dossier">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="nom">Nom: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="nom" id="nom"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="nom" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="prenom">Prénom: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="prenom" id="prenom"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="prenom" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="plaque">Plaque: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="plaque" id="plaque"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="plaque" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="permis">Permis: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="permis" id="permis"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="permis" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Mettre à jour"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

My question may seem a bit dumb, but how can I create a form which can add multiple infractions to dossier, and how to display the infractions from a dossier ?

Thank you,
Romain

Comment: It should be ManyToMany relation

Comment: In a one to many relation you don't need your table INFRACTIONDOSSIER. You should instead have and id_dossier in your table INFRACTION and make the relation with the id_dossier between the 2 tables. As pointed StanislavL the usage of a mapping table is for many to many relations.

Comment: Consider to use dedicated forms separated from Hibernate entities. Make a new AddInfractionForm class with the fields you're expect and use it instead of Hibernate entity to receive your data. Further, make your Hibernate entity from the form using your service and persist it. Using the forms a way real approach.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will try doing as you said Codemaster, using frameworks seem to be harder to me than without.. Guess it needs a lot of practice !